# Can't access website with Selenium-wire after using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, seleniumwire

I need to access a website. For that I need to use proxies with authentication and a specific user-agent. Here's the code:

```
def start_driver(proxy_data, user_agent):
    proxy = (
            proxy_data.get('login') + ':' + proxy_data.get('password') +
            '@' + proxy_data.get('ip') + ':' + proxy_data.get('port')
    )
    executable_path = os.path.abspath(r'assets\geckodriver\driver.exe')
    firefox_binary = os.path.abspath(r'assets\firefox\browser.exe')
    firefox_options = Options()
    capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile()
    # firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
    capabilities['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'eager'
    options = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': 'http://' + proxy,
            'https': 'https://' + proxy,
        }
    }
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path=executable_path,
        firefox_binary=firefox_binary,
        seleniumwire_options=options,
        capabilities=capabilities,
        firefox_profile=firefox_profile,
        firefox_options=firefox_options
    )
    driver.header_overrides = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    return driver
```

To ensure everything is okay I ping http://whatsmyuseragent.org/

```
driver.get('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/')
```

And this part of the code works fine.
However, when I get target website with:

```
driver.get('https://domain.tld/')
```

I get an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error
> page: about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=...

The curious thing about it is that when I run the script directly through PyCharm - everything works PERFECT. But after using `pyinstaller` with the following parameters:

```
pyinstaller --onefile MyScript.py
```

Selenium does reach http://whatsmyuseragent.org/ but can't reach targeted website https://domain.tld

I DO assume that the problem lies in `pyinstaller` itself but I literally CANNOT understand WHY it happens. I have only two versions to explain why it happens:

1. Issues during compiling with `pyinstaller`.
2. Targeted website somehow does not allow Selenium to reach it (but why Selenium can reach it while working out of PyCharm rather than .exe file?)

Any ideas and/or replacements to `pyinstaller`?

Comment: Did you try going to `https://domain.tld/` manually?

Comment: @Jortega yes, everything works fine. And, as I mentioned, everything works fine when running the script directly through PyCharm.

Comment: yes I am also facing same issue, it does not work with exe

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if someone else has this issue.
Go to your python folder, and find the pyinstaller hooks folder, for me that's :

https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/84#issuecomment-624389859

C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

Create a new file called :

hook-seleniumwire.py

Inside you need :

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = collect_data_files('seleniumwire')
```